# Зациклить программу

Tags: c++, циклы

Помогите разобраться с циклом.
Есть программа, которая отнимает 1 от переменной s, когда пользователь нажимает PAGE UP. Проблема в том, что не могу зациклить программу, чтобы 1 отнималось пока 500 не станет 0. Думаю, что для решения подойдет цикл do .. while, но никак не могу понять его логику. Буду благодарен любой помощи.
P.S. чтобы число отнималось каждый раз, когда пользователь нажимает PAGE UP.

Код:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int r, s = 500;
    char ch;
    while (true)
    
   do {
       // if (_kbhit())
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_PRIOR))
            {
                r = s - 1;
                std::cout << r;
                return r;
            }
    
   } while (r=s-1);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: вы же сами выходите из программы `return r;` Не будете выходить - будете по кругу бегать. Также вы не меняете нигде значение `s`, вот тут у вас `while (r=s-1);` присваивание, а не сравнение, про цикл в цикле `while (true)` я вообще не понял зачем оно.

Comment: Ну да, всё-таки while (true) здесь лишнее. Если я не пишу return r; то после нажатия PAGE UP, консоль выдает большое количество числа 499.

Comment: я же написал вам, `вы не меняете нигде значение s`, у вас `s` всегда 500, `r` всегда 499.

Comment: Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: после `r = s - 1;` напишите `s = s - 1;`. Хотя вам вообще переменная `r` не нужна, вы её можете заменить на `s` везде и ничего не изменится.

Comment: Проблема в том, что `GetAsyncKeyState` не ждёт нажатия кнопки. Она выполняется мгновенно 500 раз и проверяет, была ли нажата кнопка ДО этого или нажата ли она в данный момент. Т.е. программа в любом случае работает не так, как Вы этого хотите. Здесь и правда нужен бесконечный цикл, только не там, где он у Вас есть.

Comment: А что вы посоветуете вместо GetAsyncKeyState?

Comment: Может ли мне помочь _kbhit, если оставить GetAsyncKeyState?

Answer (score 0):

Не до конца понятно зачем вам do-while внутри while? Если вы хотите, чтобы цикл не кончался, пока s != 0, достаточного одного while. Также не понятно зачем вы делаете return внутри while, если не хотите, чтобы цикл закончился. Также, чтобы проверить переменную на равенство, нужно исспользовать "==". Вы же каждый раз присваиваете r = s - 1 внутри условия цикла.
Думаю, вы это имели ввиду:

```
int main()
{
    int s = 500;
    while (s != 0)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_PRIOR))
            {
                --s;
                std::cout << s;
            }
    }

    return 0;

}
```